# E-Mail from own local apache server with an php script

Tags: php, html, apache, email

if I set up an apache server and call a php script to send out a mail. Should that mail get actually sent out then ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how mail forwarding works, which is not a specific programming problem. Please take a __[tour]__ to learn how the site works.

Comment: "Forwarding" is not the right term here, but yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! Unless you configure an external SMTP connection.